# Trigger updating value before insert by multicating two columns

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I have to modify value of an inserted data with a trigger before. Here is my trigger :

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `Calcul_conso`;CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` TRIGGER `Calcul_conso` BEFORE INSERT ON `data` FOR EACH ROW begin 
...
DECLARE multiplicateur FLOAT DEFAULT 1;
...

SELECT multiplicateur, calcul_conso into multiplicateur, c_c from capteur where sensor_number = NEW.sensor_number;

SET NEW.value = NEW.value * multiplicateur;
...
end
```

I have the following structure :

### capteur

sensor_number (Primaire)    varchar(64) Non
nom varchar(150)    Oui NULL
multiplicateur  float   Non 1

### data

id (Primaire)   int(11) Non
sensor_number   varchar(64) Non
value   float   Oui NULL
date    datetime    Non

I tried a simple * to multiply but it seems not working.

## Sample :

new.value = 153265000 and multiplicateur = 0.001

Comment: 'I tried a simple * to multiply but it seems not working' what makes you think so?

Comment: The value is not updated. When i do it from a select, it work well, but from my trigger, it's not working

Comment: The code segment for the trigger does not syntax specifically c_c is undeclared and where does calcul_censo come from?

Comment: Don't  have variable names with the same name as column names mysql won't guess your intent.

Comment: @P.Salmon C_c is declared, but it doesn't appear in the example, replaced by ... .  I'm asking myself about the usage of float. Could it be the reason of this behavior ?

Comment: Did you check my answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your select statement looks wrong and you should not declare variables with the same name as column names.

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `Calcul_conso`;
delimiter $$
CREATE TRIGGER `Calcul_conso` BEFORE INSERT ON t 
FOR EACH ROW 
begin 

DECLARE vmultiplicateur FLOAT DEFAULT 1;

SELECT multiplicateur into vmultiplicateur from capteur where sensor_number = NEW.sensor_number;

SET NEW.value = NEW.value * vmultiplicateur;
end $$

delimiter ;
```

so given

```
drop table if exists capteur;
create table capteur
(sensor_number  varchar(64) ,
nom varchar(150) ,
multiplicateur float default 1
)
;

drop table if exists t;
create table t
(id int(11) ,
sensor_number varchar(64),
value float ,
date datetime);

insert into capteur values (1,'aaa',2);

insert into t values (1,1,10,'2018-01-01');
```

Result

```
ariaDB [sandbox]> select * from t;
+------+---------------+-------+---------------------+
| id   | sensor_number | value | date                |
+------+---------------+-------+---------------------+
|    1 | 1             |    20 | 2018-01-01 00:00:00 |
+------+---------------+-------+---------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```